# Roundcube Template Customization

Tags: php, templates, themes, skin, roundcube

I am customizing the default theme provided with roundcube. however i am facing problems while adding image in my template. the image is inside the **images** folder inside **mytheme**. i want to add that image using an **img** tag but i just cant figure out how.

I have already tried these paths..none of them are working.
    **/images/myimage.png**
    **../images/myimage.png**
    **http://local.mysite.com/images/myimage.png**
How can i insert an image residing on my own server using *img* tag?

Comment: If you want help in this concern then surely you should visit http://roundcubeskins.com/ to resolve your query. try it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your webmail installation is at the root of your url (e.g. http://mail.example.com/), try:

```
<img src="/skins/mytheme/images/myimage.png">
```